# How can I call method outside 'export default' scope in vuejs+electron?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron-builder

When I maximize window via drag titlebar electron emits 'maximize' event. I want to call 'maximize' method that exist inside 'export default' scope. How can I call?

```
<template>
    <div class="window-titlebar">
        <div class="title">{{ title }}</div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
const electron = require('electron');
import { ipcRenderer } from 'electron';

export default {
    name: 'window-titlebar',
    data() {
        return {
           title: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        maximize: function() {
            this.title = true;
        }
    }

}

ipcRenderer.on('maximize', () => {
    // I want to call 'maximize' method here
})

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to register the event handler on the component itself, that way you can tie the existence of the event handler to the lifetime of the component and the event handler will execute within the context of the component instance.

```js
export default {
    name: 'window-titlebar',
    data() {
        return {
            title: false
        }
    },
    created() {
        ipcRenderer.on('maximize', this.onMaximize)
    },
    destroyed() {
        ipcRenderer.off('maximize', this.onMaximize)
    },
    methods: {
        onMaximize() {
            this.title = true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the parent, define a reference

```
<WindowTitlebar ref="titlebar" />
```

Then call the method via `$refs`

```
this.$refs.titlebar.maximize();
```